# Rake my_string.include? limit to first result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, rake

Currently I am working on Rake task, which extracts text, and gives back a result.
In example I have object Car with attribute body, containing multiple lines of text and I need to grab lines containing word Description(case insensitive). I achieve this by running:

```
cars.each do |car|
    car.body.each_line do |line|
        if line.downcase.include? "description"
            # Rest of the code goes here
        end
    end
end
```

Works like a charm, but the problem is, there might be 10 lines in the body containing "description" and I need to grab just the first one and move on to the next object. How can I do that?

Comment: If you `break` in your if statement it will break out of the `car.body.each_line` loop and carry on to the next car. Is that what you want?

Comment: call `next` and it will ... go to the next iteration

Comment: Tried next before, did not worked, break works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Then do use [`#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) and [`String#lines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-lines) :

```
cars.each do |car|
    car.body.lines.grep(/description/) do
       # do your work
       break
    end
end
```

Example to simulate this :-

```
2.times {  ['aaa','bbbbaa'].grep(/aa/) { |m| p m.size; break } }
# >> 3
# >> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cars.each do |car|
  match = car.body.lines.select{|line| 
    line.scan(/description/i).any? 
  }.first or next
  # Do something with 'match' or you might not be here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
cars.each do |car|
  description = car.body.lines.grep(/description/).first
  if description
    # ... do your stuff with the first found description ...
  end
end
```

So, in short: search all lines that contain "description" and take the first one from that result. If there is no such line, this will return `nil`, in which case you don't need to do anything, I presume :)